# How to update nested field in an object in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, updates

Assume I have document below:

```
{
  field: {
    status: "A"
  }
}
```

I want to update status field to "B";
I used code below in Elasticsearch:

```
client.update({
          index: elasticIndex,
          id: "anything",
          doc: {
            "field.status": "B"
          }
        }).catch(console.error);
```

And got this:

```
{
  field: {
    status: "A"
  },
  "field.status": "B"
}
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
client.update({
  index: 'indexName',
  id: "id",
  body: {
    script: {
      inline: "ctx._source.status = params.status",
      lang: "painless",
      params: {
        status: "B"
      }
    }
  }
})
```